# Move lightmaps to other object? (Unity 5 lighting)

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

I have landscape with castle in center of it. I have baked all lighting.

Is there any way to remove all but castle remaining with the same lighting (on castle)?

I consider it done by getting all lightmaps and moving them to other scene with only the castle. But I can be wrong.

Will be grateful to any advice.

Answer (score 0):

### How to bake just the castle

1. Click the top right checkbox to mark it as static
2. Click on landscape and mark as un-static
3. Bake your scene

*Side note*

Lightmaps are scene specific. This means that every time you want to relight the castle in a new scene you will need to repeat the steps again.

For more info about lighting in Unity:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/introduction-lighting-and-rendering